# Where do these vectors come from?

Tags: general-relativity

I am reading [this paper](http://www.fis.puc.cl/%7Erbenguri/3.pdf) (link to pdf) by Benguria et al. *Aspects of the Hamiltonian dynamics of interacting grvitational gauge andd Higgs fields with application to spherical symmetry*

At page 13 of the paper the authors set up to solve an equation of the form:
$$\mathcal{L}_{L_{a}}A^b=[L_a,A^b]=-\epsilon_{abc}A^c$$

where $A^b$ is a vector and $L_a$ are the angular momentum components and $\mathcal{L}_L$ is the Lie derivative. The authors say that the most general solution to this equation is of the form:
$$\alpha(r)L_a+\beta(r)M_a+\gamma(r)K_a$$
where the vectors $M_a$ and $K_a$ are given by:
$$M_1=\cos\theta\cos\phi \partial_\theta-\dfrac{\sin\phi}{\sin\theta}\partial_\phi$$
$$M_2=\cos\theta\sin\phi \partial_\theta+\dfrac{\cos\phi}{\sin\theta}\partial_\phi$$
$$M_3=-\sin\theta \partial_\theta$$
$$K_1=\sin\theta\cos\phi \partial_r$$
$$K_2=\sin\theta \sin\phi\partial_r$$
$$K_3=\cos\theta \partial_r$$

and satisfy the algebra:
$$[L_a,L_b]=-\epsilon_{abc}L_c \quad [L_a,K_b]=-\epsilon_{abc}K_c \quad [L_a,M_b]=-\epsilon_{abc}M_c$$

Where do these vectors come from?